# error Error: ER_BAD_FT_COLUMN: Column 'size' cannot be part of FULLTEXT index

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, strapi, jamstack

I am developing a project with strapi.
In development mode everything Okay. When I run the project (after creating some content type) in production mode in ubuntu server with the command `NODE_ENV=production npm run start` this shows the following error -

```
error Error: ER_BAD_FT_COLUMN: Column 'size' cannot be part of FULLTEXT index
```

**Here is the screenshot -**

[image: ** Error showing in starting the project in production mode**]

Comment: Running into the same issue, you ever find a fix?

Comment: I can't remember actually how I solved it. If your project is very new then you can use the latest strapi. If you want to stick with current project, then it may be mysql table config related issue